# Can't write duplicate key, using combined primary key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and I just want to keep a relation between them, users and combines, defined by the below

```
CREATE TABLE `shocase`.`combineScorers` (
  `combineId` INT NOT NULL,
  `userId` INT NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`combineId`, `userId`),
  INDEX `combineId_idx` (`combineId` ASC),
  INDEX `userId_idx` (`userId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_combines_combineId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`combineId`)
    REFERENCES `shocase`.`combines` (`combineId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_userId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userId`)
    REFERENCES `shocase`.`users` (`userId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Nothing too fancy, combineId and userId. Both are foreign keys to their respective tables, and I'm trying to create a combined primary key as `(combineId, userId)`

When ran I'm getting the below error

> Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table 'combineScorers'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a constraint with the name `combineId` or `userId` in your database. They should be unique for the entire database. If so rename them.

Search for where the constraints are currently in use:

```
SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`
WHERE `CONSTRAINT_NAME` IN ('combineId', 'userId');
```

Comment: so that did show a result, I changed its name, re-ran the original create... and I'm getting the same error still, any other ideas?

Comment: Can you export the db and post it here?

Comment: hrmm okay not sure but there was another constraint with that same name I just didn't see, once removed all working well, thanks